# How to change date in IF statement

Tags: vb.net, date

I wish to change startDate depending on the day of the week. Here is what I've tried, the error I get is BC30311: Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'Date'.

```
Dim curr As Date = Date.Now
Dim day As String = Date.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString()

Dim startTime As New Date
If day="saturday" Then
    startTime=(curr.Year, curr.Month, curr.Day, 17, 0, 0)
Else
    startTime=(curr.Year, curr.Month, curr.Day, 13, 0, 0)
End If

Dim endTime As New Date(curr.Year, curr.Month, curr.Day, 21, 59, 0)
If (curr >= startTime) And (curr <= endTime) Then
       '''Some Code
```

I simply need to change startDate to 13:00 hours for Saturdays. Any help appreciated

Comment: Close the `"saturday"` string. use `new Date(` for startTime

Comment: Use `Dim day As DayOfWeek = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek` and `If day = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then` etc. It will proof it against string case and locale problems, and it's just as readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a better way to write code to do what you appear to want to do:

```
Dim currentDay = Date.Today
Dim startTime = currentDay.AddHours(If(currentDay.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday, 17, 13))
Dim endTime = currentDay.AddHours(21).AddMinutes(59)    
Dim currentTime = Date.Now

If currentTime >= startTime AndAlso currentTime <= endTime Then
```